# Failed to deserialize form body: invalid type: sequence, expected a string when trying to deserialize web form with Rust and Axum

Tags: forms, rust, rust-axum

I'm trying to build a simple webapp that calculates the determinant of a matrix using Rust and the Axum web framework. My current frontend implementation is a simple HTML web page with a form that firsts asks for the number of rows the matrix has, and then uses javascript to change the form so that it shows the number of rows and lets the user input each row as a string, for the backend to parse into a `Vec<i32>`.

The HTML/JavaScript code is:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <h2>Determinant Calculator</h2>
    <form action="/" method="post" id="form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <label for="row-input" id="row-input-label">Input number of rows in the square matrix
        you'd like to calculate the determinant for</label>
      <br>
      <input id="row-input" type="number">
      <button onclick="modify(event)" id="row-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% if answer -%}
    <p>The determinant of your matrix is: {{ determinant }}</p>
    {% endif -%}

  </main>
</body>

<script>
  function modify(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form = document.getElementById("form");
    let rows = document.getElementById("row-input").value;
    form.removeChild(document.getElementById("row-input"));
    form.removeChild(document.getElementById("row-input-label"));
    form.removeChild(document.getElementById("row-button"));
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      let row = document.createElement("input");
      row.type = "text";
      row.name = "row" + i;
      row.id = "row" + i;
      let label = document.createElement("label");
      label.for = "input";
      label.textContent = "row" + (i + 1) + ": ";
      form.appendChild(label);
      form.appendChild(row);
      form.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
    let submit = document.createElement("button");
    submit.type = "submit"
    submit.textContent = "Submit"
    form.appendChild(submit);
  }
</script>
```

When I start up a simple Axum backend to serve this page and process the form,
I get the error

```
Failed to deserialize form body: invalid type: sequence, expected a string
```

however, when I look at the data sent by the form on the `POST` request, it says

```
row0=1
```

if I only have one number, or something like

```
row0=1+0&row1=0+1
```

for multiple numbers.

It seems I am not properly telling the form to send the data as a string, keeping whitespace.
How can I fix this?

My axum handler is:

```rust
async fn root() -> impl IntoResponse { 
    let template = IndexTemplate { answer: false, determinant: 0, };
    Html(template.render().unwrap()) 
}
```

Comment: What does your axum handler look like?

Comment: My axum handler is 

```
async fn root() -> impl IntoResponse {
    let template = IndexTemplate {
        answer: false,
        determinant: 0,
    };
    Html(template.render().unwrap())
}

```